# Yii Framework: No Database selected

Tags: php, mysql, database, yii

I am currently trying my first steps with Yii, PHP and backend stuff. Usually I am only working with frontend apps. I came up to this error that I do not seem to find an answer to.

```
SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `country` ORDER BY `name`
Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 3D000
    [1] => 1046
    [2] => No database selected
)
↵
Caused by: PDOException

SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected
```

My Configuration in db.php

```
return [
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => 'mysql:localhost:3306;dbname=database_name',
'username' => '****',
'password' => '****',
'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `dsn` format seems wrong  try using : ( missing parameter name ,  host= and port=)

```
 'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name;port=3306',
```

Comment: That did work, now i am getting the Word "Array" in my Page but i guess thats another problem i need to get rid of! Thank You!

Comment: Done! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM database_name.`country` ORDER BY `name`
```

Also remove port:

```
return [
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => 'mysql:localhost;dbname=database_name',
'username' => '****',
'password' => '****',
'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```